# How to use find_by option in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to rails so please anybody explain me how to use find_by option in rails.
For instance the table name is  City with the field of id,city_name and country_name.

Comment: You mean that you don't understand how `City.find_by_city_name('Tokyo')` works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd use this to find a record that matches just the `city_name` field:

`City.find_by_city_name(city_name)`

You'd use this to find a record that matches the `city_name` & `country_name` fields:

`City.find_by_city_name_and_country_name(city_name, country_name)`

You probably wouldn't search for a record that matches *all* fields, because if you have the ID, then you can just get it directly with that:

`City.find(id)`

Search [this page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) for "find_by" for more details.